# How to get all rows with invalid np.datetime64 dates in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame which has a column, "date_col" with date strings. I would like to filter the DataFrame for all rows where the date strings in this column would throw a `ValueError` if parsed by `numpy.datetime64`. I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
bad_rows = df[numpy.datetime64(df["date_col"]) is False]
```

Except that instead of checking for `False`, I'd like to check whether or not a `ValueError` is raised. Is there some way to do this type of filtering in a pandas DataFrame?

I tried to do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date_col":("2015-04-31", "2015-04-30")})
result = pd.to_datetime(df["date_col"], errors='coerce')
```

But I get:

```
>>> result
0    2015-04-31
1    2015-04-30
```

Checking the type of each value reveals that they're still strings.

```
>>> result[0]
'2015-04-31'

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
date_col    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
```

If I try:

```
>>> result = pd.to_datetime(df["date_col"], errors='coerce' ,format='%Y%m%d')
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 330, in _convert_listlike
    values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 1371, in pandas.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64 (pandas/tslib.c:23790)
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 340, in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg.values, False, format)
  File "/Users/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 333, in _convert_listlike
    raise e
  File "/Users/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 307, in _convert_listlike
    arg, format, exact=exact, coerce=coerce
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 2347, in pandas.tslib.array_strptime (pandas/tslib.c:39562)
ValueError: time data '2015-04-31' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

My pandas version is 0.16.1 and my numpy version is 1.9.2.

**This works (for the pandas 0.16.1):**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date_col":("2015-04-31", "2015-04-30")})
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], coerce=True)
0          NaT
1   2015-04-30
Name: date_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], coerce=True).isnull()
0     True
1    False
Name: date_col, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Post output from df.info()

Comment: Can you try result =pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')

Comment: What's your pandas and numpy version?

Comment: OK can you try this: `result= pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], coerce=True)`

Comment: That works, thank you.

Comment: I think the issue is that the api changed in 0.17.0 so somehow my original code did nothing because of the errors, I'll update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 5):

just do `pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], errors='coerce')` this will produce `NaT` where the strings are invalid

Example:

```
In [307]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2015-02-01', 'sausage', '2011-01-33']})
df

Out[307]:
         date
0  2015-02-01
1     sausage
2  2011-01-33

In [308]:
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

Out[308]:
0   2015-02-01
1          NaT
2          NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

A subsequent call to `isnull()` will produce `True` where the values are invalid:

```
In [309]:
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').isnull()

Out[309]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

**EDIT**

Seeing as you're using `0.16.1` the api is a little different, the following should work:

```
result= pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], coerce=True)
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I try to use `pd.to_datetime` on a column of string dates, I get back a column of string dates, not a column of datetime objects.

Comment: Are you assigning back? Also edit into your question the updated code and errors