# How to convert string to date and skip record if zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried the two lines of code below and both threw the same error.

```
df['MATURITY'] = df['MATURITY'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['MATURITY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MATURITY'])
```

Error:  `ValueError: ('String does not contain a date:', ' ')`

I have a handful of records, in this one column, that are blank, and I converted those to 0, using this:  `df = df.fillna(0)`

Now, I'm guessing those zeros are causing the error I mentioned above.  Is there a way to skip these records with a 0 in this specific field, and convert all non-zeros to dates.  All these dates are strings now.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Yes I am using Pandas!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all rows with invalid np.datetime64 dates in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207339/how-to-get-all-rows-with-invalid-np-datetime64-dates-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [pandas `to_datetime` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) takes an `errors` argument which lets it respond to invalid date formatting different ways. It defaults to raising an error, but it can also be set to `'ignore'` which will return the input in case of an invalid input, e.g. 0. Try this:

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['MATURITY'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: `ignore` will return the original series. It means nothing getting done. Yous should use `coerce` and refill back on `NaT`

Comment: From the question, it seems like OP wanted to leave entries with `0` in them as they are, hence `ignore`. If that's not the case, then I will gladly edit my answer.

Comment: from your answer, I got impression that you think `ignore` will skip only error rows. It will skip everything.

Comment: That seems like it should work.  I ran this: 
df['MATURITY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MATURITY'], errors='ignore')

Then, I ran this:
df.dtypes

MATURITY is still 'object'

Any thoughts?

Comment: `coerce` followed by `.fillna(df.Maturity)`, if you want the original bad "dates" back. But this will be `object`. You can't have non-dates and the `datetime` dtype. Need to choose one or the other.

Comment: Sorry, but what, exactly do I have to do?

Comment: AndyL. it looks like you were right. I've edited my answer to reflect that.