# Find non-dates in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I find non-dates in a specific field in a dataframe?  I have dates that look like this:

```
20260521
20201207
20230130
```

When I look at the datatypes this is listed as 'object'.  I made a few attempts to coerce these items into actual dates, using the following code.

This, actually does nothing.

```
df['MATURITY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MATURITY'], errors='ignore')
```

The following two attempts throw an error.

```
df['MATURITY'] = df['MATURITY'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['MATURITY'] = pd.to_datetime(df.MATURITY)
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError: ('String does not contain a date:', ' ')
```

I can probably just delete these records, but I would like to see what they look like, before arbitrarily deleting them.  So, I have two questions:

1) How can I view these specific records, in the field named 'MATURITY' which are throwing errors?

2) Also, if I want to delete these specific records, how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all rows with invalid np.datetime64 dates in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207339/how-to-get-all-rows-with-invalid-np-datetime64-dates-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993449/how-to-convert-string-to-date-and-skip-record-if-zero

Answer (score 4):

As per [`docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), the argument `errors` in `pd.to_datetime` can be:

> errors : {‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’
>
> If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception
>
> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT
>
> **If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input**

Hence, you should use `errors='coerce'` and work with the `NaN`s

```
df['MATURITY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MATURITY'], errors='coerce')
```

1) How can I view these specific records, in the field named 'MATURITY' which are throwing errors?

```
df.loc[df['MATURITY'].isnull()]
```

2) Also, if I want to delete these specific records, how can I do it?

```
df.dropna(subset='MATURITY')
```